# How can I tell on CentOS how many node programs are currently running?

Tags: node.js, linux, centos, command-line-interface

If I have node on my machine, and I run four different node programs, is there a way for me to tell from the CLI how many programs are running?

It's usefull, I think, when I need to tell if a specific node program is on, or just to know how many programs node is running.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can always run:

```
$ ps -aef | grep node
```

Comment: thanks, but the find results that have "node" in the process name or path, so its not specific for nodsjs...

Answer (score 1):

If you're only bothered about how many:

```
$ ps aux | grep `which node` | wc -l
```

And if you actually want to see details of them, just lop the wordcount (`wc -l`( command off the end:

```
$ ps aux | grep `which node`
```

---

*NB: Using `which node` will return the location of whichever node executable is to be run by that shell, at that time - this may differ if you run it in a script somewhere, versus at your own terminal prompt, and it may differ a lot if you use [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm).  If you have multiple node binaries, you could use `grep node` but be aware that this may find other processes which include the word node, and sometimes there are many - on a dev machine it will find running versions of Slack, and other desktop apps that use node*